# Implement an ERF function in PHP

Tags: php, math

I want to implement an ERF function in PHP. I got its formula from wikipedia

```
P_Value = 1-  (  ERF ( ABS ( Residual –mean ) )/(√2*SD )
```

I didn't get the idea how to implement it in PHP.

Comment: If you want to implement some function you must know what it does.

Comment: @ Manwal, Oh. Sorry !! I meant PHP. I have edited this now. Thank you for the catch up.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Give sample output of formula you want

Comment: SD mean what, Standard Deviation? Also it looks like the ERF part is simply ERF ( ABS ( Residual –mean ) )

Comment: Give link to the page you got formula from

Comment: Anyway, integrating taylor series seem only way to (approximately) compute error function in php.

Comment: SD means standard deviation and ERF part is for whole ( ABS ( Residual –mean ) )/(√2*SD ) ). I just need to implement ERF ( x ) in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the formula you provided, only the ERF (Error function) part should look like this:

```
function ERF ($difference) {
    return abs($difference);
}
```

Now call `$value = ERF($residual - $mean);` from anywhere inside a php script to store the ERF value in the `$value` variable.

**Edit:**
Let's assume you meant this formula:

[image]

So, it should be:

```
function ERF ($ll, $ul, $t, $dt, $dx) {
     $val = 0;
     for($i = $ll; $i <= $ul; $i+=$dx){
          $val +=  exp(-pow($t,2)) * $dt;
     }
     return (2/sqrt(pi())) * $val;
}
```

now call, `$value = ERF(0, $x, $t, $dt, $dx);` where $x is the upper limit, $t is the time and $dt is the dt part of integration as in time interval.

**Note:** I've added another parameter $dx here because it is an integral for continuous domain and $dx, $dt both should be very close to 0 for better approximations. For discrete values, you can provide both $dx and $dt as 1. And that would rather be called summation than integral.

For better approximation on integration, see [Numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) algorithms and techniques.

Comment: ERF function is an integration function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function. How can I implement it in PHP ?

Comment: @Civaist, Sorry, ok. to integrate, you should implement the integration calculation manually. And you have to assume an integral range to do this.

Comment: @Civaist, did you mean this formula? http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/5/2/e529e126c9b06462fe1a9065e72dd293.png

Comment: @ Nafis. Yaa. I meant that formula.

Comment: @Civaist, please check the answer now. I hope that's pretty much the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this and write to you.

Comment: There exists a vast literature on how to efficiently implement the error function. Naive numerical integration is not the best way to go, especially for the larger arguments. There, asymptotic approximations yield better results.

Comment: @LutzL, after seeing your comment, I thought about the asymptotes a bit. At least the example formula has no asymptotes, I think. But yes, I agree, error functions could be much more complicated depending on the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to approximate the error function than by naive numerical integration. The [Wikipedia article about erf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximation) has a formula for numerical approximation. You can probably find others in Abramowitz & Stegun "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" or maybe the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov).

I found an implementation in PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-stat-percentile.php (look for the term "error function" in the text). Not sure which formula this implements.